# Open source linux Maple Worksheet Interpreter/Converter?

Tags: maple

I bought a book where the exercises are given in Maple worksheet format (.mw). Is there an open-source software in Linux able to interpret or to convert this specific file format ?

Comment: I think that this question is on-topic here. I don't know any open-source that can do that. But you can download (for free) [Maple Player](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/Mapleplayer/) that can be used for view and interact with Maple documents.  What is the book about?

Comment: The internet has [this](https://github.com/davidovitch/maple-to-python).${{{{}}}}$

Comment: @nicoguaro. Thank you, at least I can now see the code and manually translate it to something else. The book is "Natural resource and environmental economics" of R. Perman et oth.

Comment: @k20: thank you, I has been able to use the first tool there (mw2txt.py) to at least convert it to a txt file (as the Maple Player allows me to just print as image, I can't select text from there).. it's a starting point..

Answer (score 2):

Maple has a built-in function for converting the code into other languages. It is called [*Code Generation*](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/features/codegen.aspx).

You can reach a person who has Maple and ask her/him to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such luxury is available. 
As a possible solution to your problem, contact some one with maple license, so that he can copy the contents of .mw file to some text editor and mail back to you.